# Unable to get installed roles using variable

Tags: powershell

I have the below code, I can't figure out why it does not return results.

```
$List = (Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -like "*server*" -and enabled -eq "true"').name
$Role = ('RDS-RD-Server').ToString()
    
invoke-command -computername $List -scriptblock{ Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $Role -and $_.installstate -eq "installed"} | select PsComputerName, Installstate } -ErrorAction Ignore
```

If I run the get-windowsfeature with 'RDS-RD-Server' instead of using the variable, I get the expected output.

Comment: Very common mistake. The variable is defined in your local (calling) system, not on the remote system. Either define the variable in the remote scriptblock, reference it using `$using:Role` or pass it in as an argument to `Invoke-Command`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It because remote session doesn't know about local variable.

```
 $List = (Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -like "*server*" -and enabled -eq "true"').name
$Role = ('RDS-RD-Server').ToString()
    
invoke-command -computername $List -scriptblock{ Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $Using:Role -and $_.installstate -eq "installed"} | select PsComputerName, Installstate } -ErrorAction Ignore
```

Read more here [about_Remote_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-5.1)